# Bar Button Item is not Showing

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am trying to create a bottom toolbar. So I dragged I Bar Button Item to the View Controller and it was automatically position at the bottom, see image below:

[image]

But when I run the app, it doesn't show the bar at the bottom.
[image]

I already added:`self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false`

Comment: Yes, I am using Autolayout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's just only a constraints problem.
First of all check your Document Outline near to the left of your table, to see the position (toolbar is just below table):

[image]

Add your constraints and pay attention to all options as shown in the picture:

[image]

Then, take a look to the size inspector, for the table view:

[image]

And for the toolbar:

[image]

This configuration working both in portrait/landscape mode.

Comment: Sorry for this question: How do I add those constraints? I am VERY NEW in xcode.

Comment: I have upload another picture where you can set your constraints, the button below, look..

Comment: Thanks! Constraints are really driving me nuts here in xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Drag UIToolbar controller directly instead of only UIBarbutton item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set constraints of UIToolbar? I just guess it can be one of the reasons why you cannot see your barbuttoitem.

Comment: What constraints should I put?

Comment: I think you can either set the height constraint of your toolbar or set four constraints of your toolbar in the pin menu.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar and the toolbar are two different things and the toolbar is hidden by default.  Try setting the **toolbar** hidden attribute to false.

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes bar button item and bar button do not show when we present our screen. On screen we can then not see bar button item and bar button. So we need to push our screen if we want bar button item and `rightBarButtonItem`.

Comment: It would be nice with some example. Without any example, an answer isn't easy to understand.